# Add simple target to cmake generated makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, cmake

TL;DR: how can I make cmake to output the following rule in the generated makefile?

```
.PHONY: target-I-want
target-I-want:
  echo "Hello World"
```

---

Hi,

I'm used to setting projects with their own makefiles to run any type of script it may need.

The project I'm working now is being built using cmake, so I can't just make my own makefile because it will be overwritten by the one generated by cmake.

I'm setting up my own makefile with a different name, say `makefile.dev`, but since I don't want to run `make -f makefile.dev target-I-want` every time, I thought `add_custom_target` could help me.

So this is what I added to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(target-I-want
  COMMAND make -f ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/makefile.dev target-I-want
)
```

And it works. BUT when I run it, it does like a lot more that just running the command I want (`make -f ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/makefile.dev target-I-want`), like checking the cmake build system and going through a lot of automatically generated targets.

I want to know if there is a way to add the command I want just as I wrote it, with no extras.

Comment: I doubt there is a way.

Comment: [GNU make: Overriding Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding-Makefiles.html)

Comment: Well if you don't want to use make every time to build your custom target how do you expect it to run?  I would think that `cmake --build . --target target-I-want` is not much better.  It also seems that you included 'ALL' keyword in your `add_custom_target()` command.  Otherwise for me `make` just does the check if Makefiles needs to be regenerated and then runs the commands for the custom target.  You should be able to suppress the regeneration check by using `CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION`.

Comment: @Fred what I want is to be able to run `cmake .` to generate my makefile that does the compilation by just running `make`, and also I want it to have the rule so I can do `make target-I-want` instead of `make -f makefile.dev target-I-want` but with nothing else than that. What I'm currently getting is a makefile that does the compilation, has the target `target-I-want` so I can do `make target-I-want` BUT inspecting the makefile it has this rule
```target-I-want: cmake_check_build_system <linebreak>
  $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 target-I-want```
and more

Comment: @ErickSepúlveda There is a lot of boiler plate items in the Makefiles generated by `cmake`.  But running `make target-I-want` will execute the desired commands and not build lots of other things unless you made `target-I-want` depend on other `cmake` targets.  It sounds like you don't like that the Makefiles have the overhead of printing out progress of what targets are being built. I've read that you can reduce the number of status / progress items by using `CMAKE_RULE_MESSAGES`.  Personally I don't think it's a big deal that it prints 2 extra lines of text when building a custom target.

Comment: @Fred the overhead does not bother me. What I'm trying to avoid is to have to re-run `cmake .` when I change environment for a script that I know will have no issues running because it's environment independent.

Comment: @ErickSepúlveda You may want to update your question on what is exactly happening that demonstrates the issue.  You never have to re-run `cmake .` after creating the Makefiles.  Make will only re-run `cmake` to regenerate the Makefiles if something about CMakeLists.txt changes and even this behavior can be suppressed.  To be honest I don't understand why you are composing makefile.dev to run a script when add_custom_target can take any set of commands, like `echo "Hello World"` and enter it into the build.make file that is generated for the custom target.

Comment: @Fred my setup is as follows: on my machine I have my project at /my/proj. My machine does not have cmake or any of the libs required to build my project. I have a Dockerfile that does the building (`cmake . && make`) and I also run my project inside the docker container. When I make a change in a source file I have to rebuild the docker image and start again. Since I have to rebuild my docker image, all the compiling happens again. To avoid that I mount /my/proj inside the docker container, so I can do `make` and only rebuild what changed. [continues]...

Comment: @Fred The makefile that lives in my machine at /my/proj is the one generated inside de docker container. That makefile references the cmake binary at /usr/bin that the docker container has and I don't have that in my host and I don't want that. The script I'm adding through add_custom_target is a script I want to be able to run in my host machine, and if cmake added just the raw rule I'm trying to give it, it would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no command that I have seen to insert arbitrary text into the Makefiles that are generated.

Based on your comments you need to have CMake generate a custom target that does not also include the use the CMake executable itself.  While Makefile regeneration and detailed status messages can be suppressed the custom target still uses the CMake executable in the overall framework of the generated Makefiles.

If you really don't want to type `make -f makefile.dev target-I-want` then you'll have to find a alternative method like setting up an alias, or a script that invokes the command, or append the arbitrary text to the top-level Makefile that is generated by CMake.

Comment: Thanks. That's not optimal but anyway I really appreciate you trying to help :)